# Java iterative deepening search gets stuck when limit=6

Tags: java, depth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle, iterative-deepening

I'm trying to solve 15-puzzle (sliding puzzle) with iterative deepening search.

This is my initial state :

```
1 2 12 13
5 6 7 8
9 3 4 0
11 14 15 10
```

And this is my goal state :

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 0
```

I have a class of node to represent my state. This class looks like that :

```
    public List<Node> children = new LinkedList<Node>(); 
    public Node parent; 
    public static final int size = 4;
    public int[][] puzzle = new int[size][size];
    public int depth = 0;
```

And here is my search function :

```java
public List<Node> ids(Node root) {
    List<Node> path = new LinkedList<Node>();
    boolean goal = false;
    for(int limit=0; !goal; limit++) {
        path = dfs(root,limit);
        if(!path.isEmpty())
            goal = true;
    }
    return path;
}

public List<Node> dfs(Node root, int limit) {
    List<Node> path = new LinkedList<Node>();
    PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(10000, new  Comparator<Node>() {
        public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
            int depth1 = n1.depth;
            int depth2 = n2.depth;
            if(depth1 > depth2)
                return 1;
            else if(depth1 < depth2)
                return -1;
            return Node.comparePuzzle(n1.puzzle, n2.puzzle);
        }
    });
    List<Node> expendList = new LinkedList<Node>();
    List<Node> expended = new LinkedList<Node>();
    queue.add(root); 
    boolean goal = false;
    while(!queue.isEmpty() && !goal) {
        Node temp = queue.poll();
        expended.add(temp);
        if(!temp.isGoal()) {
            temp.expend();
            for(int i=0; i<temp.children.size(); i++) {
                Node child = temp.children.get(i);
                child.setDepth(temp.getDepth() + 1);
                expendList.addAll(queue);
                if(!contains(expendList,child) && !contains(expended,child) && child.depth < limit)
                {
                    queue.add(child);
                }
            }
        } else {
            goal = true;
            pathTrace(path,temp);
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

The goal state is in depth 9 of the search tree but my function gets stuck in limit 6 and I don't know why. When the goal is in depth 6 or less the function finds the solution but when the depth is more than 6 the function runs a lot of time and gets stuck.

Comment: Did you check that the test case is a solvable one ? Please post [mre] including hard coded test data.

Comment: DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]

Comment: The code you posted is **not** a [mcve]. I cannot copy it, compile it and run it.

Comment: c0der - This test case is solvable. The goal is in depth 9. The problem is that the code runs a lot of time.